# React-native redux-saga error: takeLatest$1 requires a saga parameter

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I created an App with some components and using the redux-saga in the following component:

```
// AlphaScreen.js
import ... // react & react-native
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getUser } from '../redux/ducks/user';

const AlphScreen = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUser());
    }, [dispatch]);
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  console.log(users);
  return (
    <View><Text>Blah</Text></View>
  );
}
```

```
// redux/ducks/user.js
export const SET_USER = "SET_USER";
export const GET_USER = "GET_USER";

export const setUser = (user) => ({
    type: SET_USER,
    user // user: user
});

export const getUser = () => ({
    tye: GET_USER
});

const initialState = {
    user: undefined
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
            const {user} = action;
            return {...state, user:user};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default userReducer;
```

```
// redux/defaultStore.js
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import counterReducer from './ducks/counter'
import userReducer from './ducks/user';
import { watcherSaga } from './sagas/saga';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
});

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga)
export default store;
```

```
// redux/sagas/saga.js
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { handleGetUsers } from './handlers/user';
import { GET_USER } from '../ducks/user';

export function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(GET_USER, handleGetUsers); //<- getting error takeLatest$1 requires a saga parameter
}
```

```
// redux/sagas/handlers/user.js
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { setUser } from "../../ducks/user";
import { requestGetUser } from "../requests/user";

export function* handleGetUser(action) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(requestGetUser);
        const { data } = response;
        yield put(setUser(data));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

```
// redux/sagas/request/user.js
import axios from 'axios'

const requestGetUser = () => {
    return axios.request({
        method: "get",
        url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    });
}

export { requestGetUser };
```

But I have following error:

```
takeLatest$1 requires a saga parameter
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/io-1d6eccda.js:37:10 in check
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-effects.dev.cjs.js:386:2 in validateTakeEffect
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-effects.dev.cjs.js:402:22 in takeLatest$1
at src/redux/sagas/saga.js:6:10 in watcherSaga
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1161:17 in next
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1112:6 in proc
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:1371:19 in immediately$argument_0
at node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.dev.cjs.js:60:15 in immediately
at [native code]:null in runSaga
at src/redux/configureStore.js:16:0 in <global>
at App.js:7:0 in <global>
at node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in <global>
at http://192.168.1.154:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:141908:3 in global code

The above error occurred in task watcherSaga
```

Any suggestions for fixing the error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a typo, `handleGetUsers` vs `handleGetUser` :)